# Cosa significa "grane a ritardo"?

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *Argento* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Certo saprai anche che le **grane a ritardo** sono di gran lunga le piú maligne. Mentre si cercano le cause, bisogna pure continuare a produrre: ma come puoi essere sicuro che la causa (o le cause) non sia tuttora al lavoro, e il materiale che produci foriero di altri guai? Si capisce che puoi tenerlo in quarantena due mesi e poi ricollaudarlo: ma che cosa dirai ai depositi in tutto il mondo, che non vedono arrivare roba? E gli interessi passivi? E il nome, il Buon Nome, l’Unbestrittener Ruf? Poi c’è quell’altra complicazione: ogni variazione che tu faccia nella composizione o nella tecnologia, deve aspettare due mesi prima che tu sappia se serve o non serve, se annulla il difetto o lo accentua.

Non sono riuscita a trovare la locuzione "a ritardo" su nessun dizionario. Ho trovato invece "in ritardo", per esempio, sul [De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/in-ritardo):

> **in ritardo** 
> loc.avv., loc.agg.inv.
>
> CO 
> **1** loc.avv. oltre il tempo dovuto o previsto: *finire in r. un lavoro*; *arrivare in r.* 
> **2** loc.agg.inv. di qcn. o qcs., che è o accade oltre un limite stabilito di tempo: *essere in r.*, *un ragazzo in r.  con gli studi*, *i treni in r. arrivano su un altro binario*

Le definizioni che ho visto su altri dizionari sono simili. Non mi sembra, però, che questo abbia molto senso per qualificare "grane", a meno che quello "in ritardo" sia la soluzione a tali "grane".

Sarebbe questo il senso dell'espressione "grane a ritardo"? Cioè, si tratterebbe di problemi la cui soluzione o la cui causa si trova oltre il tempo previsto o oltre il tempo auspicabile?

Answer (score 1):

Secondo me sono le "grane" che non sono immediatamente riconoscibili o i cui effetti si manifestano, appunto, in ritardo.

Answer (score 1):

È la stessa forma di *motore a scoppio*, *fucile a ripetizione*, *manica a vento*, *bomba a tempo*.

Nel caso specifico, le *grane a ritardo* sono quelle che si insinuano senza farsi notare e il cui effetto sarà evidente più avanti. Perché sono *maligne*? Perché è difficile capire quale sia la causa della grana.